# JavaEE cluster vs PaaS

Tags: jakarta-ee, heroku, wildfly, paas

I have been developing web apps with Java since a few years, deploying on Tomcat. Recently, I and my clients got pissed off by downtime due to hardware failure on the server and also by the necessity of redeploying the application each time I do a fix.

I want the next application I'll develop to be highly available. Right now I feel like I'm in front of two choices:

1- Do a stateless application and use a PaaS like heroku, or maybe manage multiple instances on my own servers

2- Create a stateful application with JavaEE and deploy on a cluster of application servers

As a developer, I would really love to focus on app development rather than on the infrastructure. So stateless + cloud service seems like the way to go.

On the other hand, I really love stateful applications because I find it much easier to develop in such a manner.

So here is the question: how hard is it to manage and setup a JavaEE cluster? I would probably choose wildfly as application server. I have heard from many people that it can really be a pain in the ass: managing the linux server, configuring the AS, troubleshooting, managing the cluster etc.

Does it really require a skilled guy to handle a cluster for enterprise services? I once thought that it would be as easy as installing the AS on the machine, doing some minutes of configuration and then just letting it run.

Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry user3832044 but I don't understand your concept of "stateless" and "stateful" applications. It seems that your problem is an infrastructure problem, not an application problem.

So, answering your question...
"How hard is to manage and setup a JavaEE cluster?"
As hard as building a raft. If you know what to do, it's not hard.
It all depends on your skills as a system administrator.

There are many ways to solve your problem and you don't even need to go away from Tomcat as it supports clustering and Load balancing.

I would recommend you to read about high availability to gather some general knowledge about the topic and then apply it to Tomcat.

To give you an example. You could have a couple of tomcat instances with an Apache http doing Load Balance in front of your instances. You could stop one of the instances and deploy the new app and then swap the instances and update the second one.

Plz keep in mind that this example is a very simple process for a simple environment. Things can get really hairy in more complex environments.

Here is a quick tutor to help you with the Load balance.
http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/ApachePlusTomcat_HowTo.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that tomcat supports session replication, but I would rather do that with an application server as I could use frameworks like JSF and EJB if I happen to develop apps which need a state. If I understand correctly how tomcat clustering works, I would have to attach everything to the user session.

Comment: There are confusions some times about clustering and load balancing on Tomcat. For as much as they overlap each other, they are different things. Load Balancing is actually done by Apache httpd (web server) and tomcat instances behind that don't even need to know about each other. Clustering is when your Tomcat instances know about each other and therefore become able to session replicate and deploy in cluster etc. RE the app state, I think you are misunderstand application states. Many major applications run just using Tomcat. I use full app server but Tomcat work just as fine.